# How to transform the tab of selected values in a select(html) into a field in symfony2

Tags: php, html, symfony

i have to work on a project with symfony2.
I have to create a form with many select input. These select inputs can have more one value selected. 
I want to insert all the selected values in one field like that :

```
value 1
value 2
value 3

result => value1;value2;value3
```

So I don't have to have a one-to-many relation.

How can I do that, knowing each select input is generated thanks to their entity ?

and when I want to submit i have this error :

```
Warning: oci_bind_by_name(): Invalid variable used for bind in [...]/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/OCI8/OCI8Statement.php line 156 

     ->add('cod_rom','entity',array(
            'label' => 'Codes romes :',
            'class' => 'xxxxListeBundle:CodeRome',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'property' => 'libelle'
        ))
```

Comment: Please provide some code to work on.

Comment: And now ?  Is it enough ?

Comment: I don't work with PHP but as per your warning message the warning is being generated from `oci_bind_by_name()` . Where is this function/method declared/called? The more information you provide the more response you'll get here. :)

Comment: %myproject%/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/OCI8/OCI8Statement.php line 156

Comment: @shinobivdk, can you paste the code of your entities, and the code of the form building?

Comment: Sorry, I can't for the moment. For now I will try by using hidden fields autocompleted by chose value on the list.

Then submitting the hidden fields.